# Two flushes on the same thread GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I have two flushes on the same thread using GORM, is it possible for the first to pass and the second to fail in separate transactions?

Or even if I just have one flush half way thru the thread and then a second implicit flush after the request finishes, is it is possible for the second to fail but the changes from the explicit flush to pass and thus be persisted in the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I have two flushes on the same thread using GORM, is it possible for the first to pass and the second to fail in separate transactions?

It's the transactions that succeed/fail, not the flushes. There's an implicit flush at the end of every transaction, and also at the end of every session (request). It's absolutely possible to have several transactions in the same thread, some of which fail, and some of which succeed. For example, given a simple domain class

```
class Book {
  String title
}
```

The first transaction in `someAction` will succeed and the second will be rolled back.

```
class MyController {

  def someAction() {

    Book.withTransaction {
      new Book().save(title: 'successful').save(failOnError: true)
    }

    Book.withTransaction {
      new Book().save(title: 'failed').save(failOnError: true)
      throw new RuntimeException('transaction rollback')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if I don't use withTransaction but invoke flush several times, is it all still definetly the one atomic transaction?

Comment: If you don't put your code inside `withTransaction` or a service method (which are transactional by default), you don't have *any* transactions

Comment: As Don mentioned if you don’t specify transactional boundaries (via `withTransaction` or the `@Transactional` transform on a service) then your database connection is in auto-commit mode and a flush will save any changes automatically since there is no transaction present.